# AJAX POST TO PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

dataString is :

```
{"feedback_type":"000","error_type":"","textarea":"blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"}
```

I used the following code to post to the PHP:

```
// ajax post
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "core/poster.php" ,
    data:  dataString,
    success:function()
    {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});

return false;
```

And php file:

```
<?php

require 'Class_DBOperation.php';
require 'global.php';

// Establish Database Connection
$dbOperation = new class_DBOperation(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPWD,DBNAME,DBCHARSET);

// Receive dataString
$content=$_POST['feedback_type'];
$run=mysql_query("insert into reports values (NULL, '".$content."')");

?>
```

The problem is why $content is empty?
What should I do ? any ideas?

Comment: Odd to use a name like `dataString` for an object.

Comment: BTW, <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.1.4.0.js"></script> is the jquery-version I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Add a response in your success function and alert it

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "core/poster.php" ,
    data:  dataString,
    success:function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And in your poster.php file try adding the following to the top within the PHP tag.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
var_dump($_POST);
```

This should give you a place to start and debug what's going on.

Comment: firebug told me that:                                            array(0) {
}
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  feedback_type in <b>C:\Software\xampp\htdocs\poster.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

Comment: That would mean that `$_POST['feedback_type']` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a direct solution, but it may help you find out what is wrong.  Try dumping out the contents of your $_POST superglobal, this will inform you of how the data was received.  Try something like:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r ($_POST);
print '<pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your double quotes for parameter names

```
{
   feedback_type: "000",
   error_type: "",
   textarea: "blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"
}
```

Comment: not work :( ,  BTW, <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.1.4.0.js"></script> is the jquery-version I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a JSON string as the parameter string.

Parameters should be formatted as follows:

`foo=bar,foo2=bar2,foo3=bar3` etc...

You could either reformat the string to follow the norm:

**JS**:

```
var dataString = "feedback_type=000&error_type=&textarea=blahblahblah";
```

**PHP**:

```
echo $_POST['feedback_type']; // 000
echo $_POST['error_type']; // null
echo $_POST['textarea']; // blahblahblah
```

or you could pass the JSON string as a POST parameter:

**JS**:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "feedback_type" : "000",
    "error_type" : "", 
    "textarea" : "blahblah"
}


var jsonString = '{"feedback_type":"000","error_type":"","textarea":"blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"}';

// OR

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

var dataString = "json_string=" + jsonString;
```

**PHP**:

```
// String - suitable for database input
echo $_POST['json_string']; // String: {"feedback_type":"000","error_type":"","textarea":"blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah"}

// Parse into array
$json_array = json_decode($_POST['json_string']);
```